# Are weak pointers guaranteed to have expired by the time the std::shared_ptr deleter runs?

Tags: c++, c++11, c++14, shared-ptr

If I have a `std::shared_ptr<Foo>` with a custom deleter, is it guaranteed that all associated weak pointers are seen as expired by the deleter? (I would appreciate it very much if you could cite relevant sections in the standard.)

In other words is the assertion below guaranteed not to fire?

```
std::weak_ptr<Foo> weak;
std::shared_ptr<Foo> strong{
  new Foo,
  [&weak] (Foo* f) {
    assert(weak.expired());
    delete f;
  },
};

weak = strong;
strong.reset();
```

Comment: Well the use counter will be zero before the deleter is called, and [this `expired` reference](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/weak_ptr/expired) says that it is "Equivalent to `use_count() == 0`". The reference is not authoritative, you need to go through the specification to find the definitive answer (drafts of the C++11, C++14 and C++17 standards are all available for free, the last draft before ratification are good enough).

Comment: Agreed. But a definitive answer from the standard is exactly what I'm asking for. :-) I haven't yet found one for myself.

Comment: I think this is implied: if your assertion weren't true, then you could replace it with `weak.lock()` (and perhaps move the ownership out), and then the destructor for the shared object would be running twice.

Comment: @KerrekSB: How can you "imply" something like that? A specification defines behavior, and if the spec doesn't explicitly define that the behavior of this, then it is undefined. Oh, I think it's clear that the specification's *intent* is to decrement the counter before destroying the object. But if intent and wording don't agree, then that's a defect.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is apparently nothing in the C++14 standard that guarantees this. I've now opened a [defect report](http://cplusplus.github.io/LWG/lwg-active.html#2751) for the standard covering the problem.

Comment: Your defect report has been updated. They seem to consider this to be not a defect: deleters should not be poking about with such things, and the implementation burden to allow it would apparently be more than they want to fix it.

Comment: Yeah, I saw that. Honestly I don't understand what the implementation burden they refer to is.

Answer (score 8):

The standard guarantees nothing. For `shared_ptr`'s destructor, the spec only says:

> - If `*this` is empty or shares ownership with another `shared_ptr` instance (`use_count()` > 1), there are no side effects.
> - Otherwise, if `*this` owns an object `p` and a deleter `d`, `d(p)` is called.
> - Otherwise, `*this` owns a pointer `p`, and delete `p` is called.
>
>   [Note: Since the destruction of `*this` decreases the number of instances that share ownership with *this by one, after `*this` has been destroyed all `shared_ptr` instances that shared ownership with `*this` will report a `use_count()` that is one less than its previous value. —end note ]

And `reset` is defined in terms of swapping a `shared_ptr` into a temporary, which is then destroyed.

So the spec only guarantees that the state of `use_count` will be zero *after* the destructor has finished. Exactly when during that process it is set to 0 is not specified.

Comment: Thanks, this was my understanding of the problem too, but you've nailed the heart of it. :-) I guess I'll have to rely on the fact that it would be very dangerous for an implementation to do anything else (because you could resurrect a `std::shared_ptr<Foo>` to an object that's currently being deleted).

Comment: @jacobsa: You could file a defect report on it. They might have a fix for the wording for C++17.

Comment: Thanks, I've now filed a defect report.