# How to make not owning pointers like shared_ptr?

Tags: c++

In my resource manager, the createTexture method should produce a pointer to the texture. And I want to delete a resource when only the manager owns it. How can I achieve this? If I use shared_ptr, the resource manager will store its shared_ptr pointer to the texture and will not be able to delete it.

```
class ResourceManager
{
    vector<shared_ptr<Texture>> _textres;

public:
    shared_ptr<Texture> CreateTexture()
    {
        auto tex = shared_ptr<Texture>(new Texture);
        _textures.push_back(tex);
        return tex;
    }
}

int main
{
    ResourceManager rm;

    {
        auto tex = rm.CreateTexture();
        // Do something with texture...
    }

    // Problem here: ResourceManager doesn't remove the texture because he owns it
}
```

Comment: Why does the manager need to hold on to the texture?

Comment: Do you want a [`std::weak_ptr`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/weak_ptr)?

Comment: One approach (assuming you can't just get rid of the `_textures` vector entirely) would be to have `_textures` hold objects of type `weak_ptr<Texture>` instead of `shared_ptr<Texture>`.   https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/weak_ptr

Comment: Resource manager must know memory usage for all textures. I also want to make a special logic when deleting a texture (asynchronously in another thread).

Comment: So you just want the resource manager to be notified somehow when a texture is deleted elsewhere, but not actually to keep it alive? Which thread should your special logic be executed in?

Comment: How does the resource manager know that the number of references == 0?

Comment: @Useless Yes, I want the resource manager to be notified that no one else uses the texture and it can be released. Inside the resource manager there is a thread that removes resources.

Comment: ResourceManager can use the `use_count` method to make sure no other owners for the resource and destroy it. https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/shared_ptr/use_count

Comment: So you want to make sure destructor of the resource runs in a specific thread?

Comment: @balki checking all counters in all textures can take a long time

Comment: @balki It shouldn't matter which thread it happens in, if you use proper synchronisation

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you need is:

- A vector of `weak_ptr` instead of `shared_ptr`
- A `shared_ptr` whose deleter function (invoked when no more non-weak references are in scope) looks up the object in the vector and removes that entry

A custom deleter may be provided using the `shared_ptr` constructor. Be sure to actually do the deletion as well, because that behaviour will no longer be automatic.

Also be careful about [some confusions with respect to `weak_ptr` behaviour during deleter invocation](https://stackoverflow.com/q/38426719/560648); you could always [switch to a raw pointer instead](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19066388/560648) which basically has the same effect without any of the burning questions.

Note that this change makes your manager no longer "own" the textures, but per your described semantics (*"delete a resource when only the manager owns it"*) it never really did anyway.

Comment: Thank. It seems to best idea is store a raw pointer, and provide custom deleter

Comment: If you make it a little intrusive into the class (or wrap the class in a helper), it could hold a reference to itself and not have to lookup the texture -- a trade-off of space for time.

Comment: @metal Arguably yes, but I think you'll find some people questioning such a self-referential design

Comment: @pushрор Basically. Though, for the record, I put this into production with `weak_ptr` and never had a problem

Answer (score 2):

I think what you're asking for is a `shared_ptr` that invokes a callback when the count is decremented to 1. Your manager registers for that callback in the `CreateTexture()` function when it creates the smart pointer and then checks whether to invoke it whenever someone decrements the reference count.

Corner case to watch out for: the count will start as 1, and you don't want to delete it then.

Compare the [C++ FAQ's implementation](http://www.cs.technion.ac.il/users/yechiel/c++-faq/ref-count-simple.html) of an intrusive reference-counted smart pointer as a starting point. The work ahead of you is to add a `std::function` or other callable to be invoked at the right time.

Implementing smart pointers can be a little tricky, especially when you mix in threading, but for other starting points, you can compare implementations from [`boost::shared_ptr`](https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_69_0/libs/smart_ptr/doc/html/smart_ptr.html#shared_ptr), which became standardized, and [Loki](https://github.com/snaewe/loki-lib)'s [`SharedPtr`](https://github.com/snaewe/loki-lib/blob/master/include/loki/SmartPtr.h), which is described in the classic *Modern C++ Design* by Alexandrescu.

An alternative to re-implementing `shared_ptr` would be to use its custom deleter to invoke the callback, but you'll have to play some games to make that work.

Comment: Does this mean that I need to re-implement the shared_ptr with callback in constructor?

Comment: Yes, you would pass the callback in at creation of the smart pointer and then call the callback in the smart pointer's destructor.